# How to get the value element [@attributes] with arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

```
<function name="getMemberInfo">
    <component name="people">
        <property name="ppl_firstname">
            <![CDATA[ Jamie ]]>
        </property>
    </component>
</function>
```

I am trying to retrieve the ppl_firstname. The XML showend above is part of the code which has been parsed by an API url.

I have used curl to get the url contents

```
$url=""
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents
$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);
```

Then i have put the data in an array

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xmlJson = json_encode($xml);
$xmlArr = json_decode($xmlJson, 1); // Returns associative array
```

which outputs like this:

```
Array ( [@attributes] => 
    Array ( [name] => getMemberInfo ) [component] => 
        Array ( [0] => 
            Array ( [@attributes] => 
                Array ( [name] => people ) [property] => 
                    Array ( [0] => Jamie [1] )
                  )
              )
       )
```

Can anyone tell me how i can retrieve the name. Thanks in advance

Comment: What name? `Jamie`? `people`? `memberInfo`?

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder i need the property value <![CDATA[ Jamie ]]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is first access the child `property` then you can access this child's attributes.

```
$xml_string = '<function name="getMemberInfo">
                     <component name="people">
                          <property name="ppl_firstname">
                               <![CDATA[ Jamie ]]>
                          </property>
                     </component>
                 </function>';
$function = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$component= $function->children();
//access your property children
$property = $component->children();
$property_name = $property->attributes()->name;
//check if it prints the right name
echo "Property name: ".$property_name
```

Comment: I'm glad it did! @JamieYouell